# Python Code to get text between the table tags

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am new to Python, can someone help me in writing the code where I can get the data from the tags?

The below is the table tag, also I need the data which is present in the table which is inside the first table:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr> 
                    <td width="7" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width='40%'> <div align="left">

                      </div>
                    <td width="7" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr> 
                    <td colspan="2"> 
    <b><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>Account #: 8428995632 </font></b><BR><TABLE BORDER='1' width='100%' align='center' cellspacing='0'><TR><td align='left' colspan='2'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Billing Date:   </b><BR>07-22-2013</font></TD><td align='left' ><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Past Due Date:    </b><BR>08-12-2013</font></TD></TR><TR><td align='left'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Service From: </b><BR>06-11-2013</font></TD><td align='left'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Service To:    </b><BR>07-11-2013</font></TD><td align='left'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Days of Service: </b><BR>30</font></TD></TR><TR><td align='left' colspan='2'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Current Charges:    </b>$30,488.60</font></TD><td align='left' ><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Amount Due:   </b>$30,488.60</font></TD></TR></TR></TABLE><p><p><p><p><CENTER><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='3'><b> Meter readings for this bill:</b></font></CENTER><TABLE BORDER='1' width='100%' align='center' cellspacing='0'><TR bgcolor='#FFF2D7'><td align='center' width='18%'><font face='Arial,Helvetica,  sans-serif' size='2'><b>Meter</b></font></TD><td align='center' width='17%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Service<br>From</b></font></TD><td align='center' width='17%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Service<br>To</b></font></TD><td align='center' width='12%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b># Days</b></font></TD><td align='center' width='10%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Prior<br>Read</b></font></TD><td align='center' width='10%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Current<br>Read</b></font></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'><b>Consumption</b></font></TD><TR><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif' size='2'>S10406906</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='18%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>06-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='12%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>07-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>30</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>134</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='22%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>144</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>10</FONT></TD></TR></FONT><TR><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif' size='2'>08400002</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='18%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>06-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='12%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>07-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>30</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>30748</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='22%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>32634</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>1886</FONT></TD></TR></FONT><TR><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif' size='2'>S10406911</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='18%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>06-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='12%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>07-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>30</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>2717</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='22%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>3046</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>329</FONT></TD></TR></FONT><TR><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif' size='2'>08405704</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='18%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>06-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='12%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>07-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>30</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>23755</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='22%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>25100</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>1345</FONT></TD></TR></FONT><TR><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif' size='2'>S10406895</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='18%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>06-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='12%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>07-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>30</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>97</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='22%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>101</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>4</FONT></TD></TR></FONT><TR><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif' size='2'>S10406893</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='18%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>06-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='12%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>07-11-2013</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='8%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>30</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>7915</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='22%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>8406</FONT></TD><td align='center' width='16%'><font face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif' size='2'>491</FONT></TD></TR></FONT></TABLE><input type='hidden' name='BillId' value='842892230704'></form>

                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
```

The code I have used is:

```
print BS('table')[0].text
```

But this gets only the first table content.

thanks for the help.

Comment: Once again, don't post just one line of your code or just say `257 line` of your code. Try to post more description of what you actually need or want. From a look of it, there will be really simple answer. But you're not getting one due to unclear question. What exactly you need script to output?

Answer (score 0):

No *really* sure what the OP is asking for here, but this is what I got out of the question:

> The below is the table tag, also I need the data which is present in the table which is inside the first table:

From this sentence, I suspect you want the one line of text within the outer `<table>`, along with the text from the ***first* inner** `<table>`.There are many ways to go about this in `BeautifulSoup`, but this way made the most sense to me.

```
# The variable "html" contains your sample html.
font_tags = html.findAll( 'font' )

# Now we print each piece of data wrapped in a <font> tag
for font_tag in font_tags:
    # This begins the second inner table, and we don't want that.
    if font_tag.text == u" Meter readings for this bill:":
        break
    else:
        print font_tag.text
```

This prints the following:

```
Account #: 8428995632 
Billing Date:   07-22-2013
Past Due Date:    08-12-2013
Service From: 06-11-2013
Service To:    07-11-2013
Days of Service: 30
Current Charges:    $30,488.60
Amount Due:   $30,488.60
```